# AWS SQS message forwarding to next sqs service not showing cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

Disclaimer: newbie in aws arena

I have an endpoint that send message to an sqs queue to process order, once process order is done it forward that message to another queue to process payment.

I successfully send my message to first queue to process order, and that also prints success message saying message has been forward to process payment queue, however, I cannot see any logs printing in the cloudwatch logs.

I have created a serverless.yml file for process order repo.

```
service: process-order

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-domain-manager

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage:  ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}.stage}
  region: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}.region}
  deploymentBucket: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}.bucket}
  environment:
    MESSAGE: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}.me

iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - "sqs:SendMessage"
    Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:eu-east-2:996333333061:ApiPaymentTest"

functions:
  compute:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:eu-east-2:996333333061:ApiPaymentTest
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - ApiPaymentTest
              - Arn
          bacthSize: 1
```

Looking forward for your expert opinion please.

regard

Comment: Are you saying that you see NOTHING in CloudWatch Logs, or you simply don't see a _particular message_ in CloudWatch Logs (but you do see other messages)? If you are seeing nothing, then it would be because you have not given the function the necessary permissions to send to CloudWatch Logs. Take a look at the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy to see the `logs:` permissions to provide.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein, yes I cannot see any log at all. I will try implementating your suggestion.